# I can't get getCurrentCategory() from inside my custom block. How can I get this?

Tags: category, blocks

I put some of my custom blocks on the **category page**. I can't get the **getCurrentCategory()** from the template (nor from the block). What is the cause of this?

I know that I can get the current category with: 
 `Mage::registry('current_category')` , but I prefer the method that worked for me before, which is `$this->getCurrentCategory();`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution would be to not do cut and paste coding, replicating methods that already exists.

Why not just extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` from your own class, which in turn extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` thus giving you the methods you require.

`class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`

You can also extend the methods:

`getCacheKeyInfo()` and `_construct()` to derive your own cache options for your custom block.

Comment: Sounds like a bit better solution than my own, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Not all blocks have this method apparently. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` has it, but 
`Mage_Core_Block_Template` doesn't have it. And I was extending my block from this block, naturally. I resolved this by simply adding the whole method `getCurrentCategory()` to my custom block from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` (Navigation.php).